# Replace with regular expression in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this regular expression:

```
var a = window.location.href.replace(/((.*)[&|?])(sessionid(=[^&]*))([&|#](.*))/, '$1$5');
```

That remove the sessionid from an example url like this:

```
http://...&parent_location=Test&abc=123&sessionid=q26bh6bkm8g49aeopem2obdm87igrsfe&...
```

The result will be:

```
http://...&parent_location=Test&abc=123&&...
```

My question is, if in that replace I can add the replace also for the `parent_location`

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: 1. Parse the URL/query string into an array/object. 2. Manipulate the data as needed. 3. Reformat into a URL. - Much saner than regexen.

Comment: This result: http://...&&abc=123&&... I wan't remove also the parent_location query string, would be appreciate remove also the & not needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use single regex with unnecessary capturing group removed.

```
str.replace(/([&?])(?:sessionid|parent_location)=[^&#]*(?=[&#]|$)/m, '$1')
```

[DEMO](https://www.regex101.com/r/UHF7n2/1)

Comment: Doesn't work with an ash tag http://...&parent_location=Test&abc=123&sessionid=q26bh6bkm8g49aeopem2obdm87igrsfe#abc/abc should remain: http://...&abc=123#abc/abc

Comment: just add `#` inside the first character class.. ie, `[&?#]`

Answer (score 0):

You can add several .replace methods in a row.

```
var a = window.location.href
    .replace(/((.*)[&|?])(sessionid(=[^&]*))([&|#](.*))/, '$1$5')
    .replace(/*statement*/);
```